# PHP/Regex: Remove everything up to first word with at least 2 letters but include numbers that are touching the start of the word

Tags: php, regex

How do I remove everything up to first word with at least 2 letters, but include numbers that are touching the start of the 2+ letters? The below code currently removes everything up to the first letter.

```
$test = "1234 123423-34 b4 3-z a 234 This is a test";
echo preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $test);
```

Should output:
This is a test

```
$test = "1234 123423-34 b4 3-z a 234This is a test";
echo preg_replace('/^[^A-Za-z]+/', '', $test);
```

Should output:
234This is a test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
/^.*?(?=\d*[a-z]\d*[a-z]|$)/i
# ^  ^------ lookahead: followed by a "word" with 2 letters or the end of the string 
# '--------- any character + non-greedy quantifier: all characters until
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFZg9j/1)

The same in unicode:

```
/.*?(?=\d*\pL\d*\pL|$)/Au
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/XFZg9j/2)

Answer (score 0):

Another one with word boundaries:

```
^.*?(?=\b\d*(?i)[a-z]{2,}\b)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/OHLZgl/1).